# jQuery.height() behaves differently in WebKit and Firefox when using box-sizing:border-box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, webkit

I have a textarea with the following style applied:

```
textarea {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

If I then run the following javascript/jquery code, my textarea's height gets cut in half using Safari(5.0.6) and Chrome(16.0.x):

```
$('textarea').each( function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.height( $this.height() );
}
```

According to the jQuery docs for .height(), this is the expected behavior because .height() returns the content height (no padding, border), regardless of the box-sizing property, but .height( value ) sets the content size *accounting for* the box-sizing property. So if my textarea has content-height:17px and padding-height:15px, .height() will return 17px. Then, if I set .height(17) my textarea that used to be 32px high is now only 17px high.

My real-world application is using jQuery.fn.autoResize 1.14 (https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery.fn.autoResize) on textareas that have box-sizing applied. That code pulls a similar stunt to what I've described above.

It works fine in FireFox 10. (That is, FireFox accounts for box-sizing in a more symmetrical way when getting and setting height.)

My question is: Where is the bug, and where should I look for/propose a workaround? The jQuery.fn.autoResize plugin, the jQuery team, webkit, or FireFox?

Comment: Would using jQuery('#container').outerHeight(); work any better? I've found problems with this as well and it's tricky to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bug is in jQuery (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11004) that makes `$(el).height()`  not account for the `box-sizing` property. The fix is scheduled to go out in v1.8, however in the mean time you can use `$(el).outerHeight()` to get the height of the box accounting for padding and border (http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/).

Comment: `$.height` and `$().height` are different things. The former is not defined, and a static method of `jQuery`, the latter is an instance method.

Comment: @RobW - thanks, I clarified my meaning a bit to avoid confusion

Answer (score 4):

Bug in jQuery calculations.

Solution:

```
var height = $this.outerHeight() - Number($this.css('padding-top').split('px')[0]) - Number($this.css('padding-bottom').split('px')[0]);
```

If you have borders - also calculate them

Comment: has this been reported to the jquery team?