# android view + jquery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, webview

i am developing an android app using webview GUI. i have a  element which contains the page.It has a header and a footer.

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    ...
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" id="bg_im">
    ...
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

i would like to insert an image as a background of content div in such a way that the whole content does not take more space than the available screen size.

i have a javascript that does that:

```
document.getElementById("bg_im").style.height=Math.floor($(window).height() - $('#home_header').height() - $('#home_footer').height() +"px";
```

the function is executed when the page is loaded.

it all works well in desktop browser (chrome, mozilla), but fails when loaded inside webview in android. i found out that the reason is that the function `.height()` for header and footer returns a value of 0.

any idea why? i tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627973/jquery-header-height-returns-0-on-subsequent-pages) but it doesn't work either.  it still returns header/footer size 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is probably coming from your Math.floor() method. You are mixing string concatenation and arithmetic operations. You should separate those statements.

```
var newHeight = Math.floor($(window).height() - $('#home_header').height() - $('#home_footer').height()); 
$('#bg_img').prop('height', newHeight);
```

Comment: i don't think that's the problem. it does return a number, which in this case equals to $(window).height(). also , if i print out $('#home_header').height(), it prints a 0. same for footer.so the problem is that it does not subtract the header and footer size because both numbers are 0 and i can't figure out why.

Comment: Are you calling these methods within the $(document).ready({}); function (http://api.jquery.com/ready/)? If the document is not ready the div heights could be zero. You could also check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095967/jquery-height-behaves-differently-in-webkit-and-firefox-when-using-box-sizing

Comment: yes, the function is called in the following way:$(document).ready(function(){  
   resizeContent();
   $(window).resize(function() {
       resizeContent();
    });
});